# Jinja2 - Process variable from Flask view

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a Flask application that allows users to define templates for certain sections within a main Jinja2 template.  Is it possible to have Jinja process a variable from a string?  For example, application view passes the below variable:

```
report.summary='<p>This is a report for {{ user.first_name }}.</p>'
```

The relevant portion from the Jinja template is:

```
<h1>Summary</h1>
{{ report.summary }}
```

The rendered output is:

> **Summary**
>
> This is a report for {{ user.first_name }}.

Can Jinja process `{{ user.first_name }}`, or am I forced to do the variable substitution myself from flask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `render_template_string`.

```
report.summary=render_template_string(r'<p>This is a report for {{ user.first_name }}.</p>', user)
```

Documentation: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.render_template_string

---

Otherwise, why have HTML in your class fields when you can just pass both the user and the report to the template?

Comment: This works, thanks.  I used your suggestion to update the modified fields (i.e. report.summary), then passed them to the normal render_template function for the final implementation.